# CSS-only dropdown menu doesn't always work on iPhone

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, drop-down-menu

I have a basic CSS dropdown menu for a client on a Wordpress-based sites. It is just CSS styling, no JS, and works perfectly on desktops.

However we've realized that the menu only works intermittently on iPhones, maybe every 2 or 3 page loads, but most of the time is broken and doesn't allow any access to any of the subpages.

What happens is the dropdown menu expands on tap, as it should, but then the links in the dropdown don't work. Tapping them closes the menu and does nothing, or, since the site logo falls underneath the dropdown, acts like you tapped the logo and redirects back to the homepage.

Pressing and holding on the link in the dropdown brings up the normal link options (copy, open in new window, etc) so I know it is recognizing the link, it just doesn't want to behave normally on a single tap.

The menu works perfectly on iPads, just not iPhones (which doesn't make sense at all to me). I feel like if the issue was consistent, happening all the time across all mobile safari devices, I might be able to figure this out, but the intermittent nature of it has me stumped. Additionally, I've used pretty much an identical menu code on another client's site, and theirs is working perfectly on all devices. I've tried removing plugins, ads, other scripts on the site (like the Hellobar for example) to see if it is a conflict, but nothing seems to consistently fix the issue.

Site in question is http://www.twopeasandtheirpod.com/. See the dropdown under 'About' and 'On the Side'.

Any assistance in troubleshooting this would be greatly appreciated!

Structure of the menu is wordpress' default menu structure. CSS being used for reference:

```
.centeredmenu {
color: #fff;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: MergeRegular, Arial, sans-serif, Helvetica;
clear: both;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
border: none;
font-weight: normal;
text-transform: lowercase;
z-index: 100;
position: relative;
height: 30px;
line-height: 30px;
background-color: #65b020;
}

/* Top menu items */
.centeredmenu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
float: right;
position: relative;
right: 50%;
}
.centeredmenu ul li {
margin: 0 3px;
padding: 0;
float: left;
position: relative;
left: 50%;
}
.centeredmenu ul li a {
display: block;
margin: 0;
padding: 0 12px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ffffff;
}
.centeredmenu ul li.active a {

}
.centeredmenu ul li a:hover {
color: #bbda6d;
}
.centeredmenu ul li:hover a,
.centeredmenu ul li.hover a { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
color: #bbda6d;
}

/* Submenu items */
.centeredmenu ul ul {
display: none; /* Sub menus are hiden by default */
position: absolute;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
top: 30px;
line-height: 24px;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
text-transform: lowercase;
right: auto; /*resets the right:50% on the parent ul */
width: 160px; /* width of the drop-down menus */
background-color: #65b020;

}
.centeredmenu ul ul li {
left: auto;  /*resets the left:50% on the parent li */
padding: 0;
margin: 0; /* Reset the 1px margin from the top menu */
clear: left;
width: 100%;
}
.centeredmenu ul ul li:before {
display: none;
}
.centeredmenu ul ul li a,
.centeredmenu ul li.active li a,
.centeredmenu ul li:hover ul li a,
.centeredmenu ul li.hover ul li a { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
margin: 0;
padding: 7px 12px;
line-height: 1.4;
color: #ffffff;
}
.centeredmenu ul ul li a:hover,
.centeredmenu ul li.active ul li a:hover,
.centeredmenu ul li:hover ul li a:hover,
.centeredmenu ul li.hover ul li a:hover { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
background-color: #77c12e;
}

/* Flip the last submenu so it stays within the page */
.centeredmenu ul ul.last {
left:auto; /* reset left:0; value */
right:0; /* Set right value instead */
}

/* Make the sub menus appear on hover */
.centeredmenu ul li:hover ul,
.centeredmenu ul li.hover ul { /* This line is required for IE 6 and below */
display:block; /* Show the sub menus */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're using `:hover` states which are at-best buggy, and at-worst will never work on touchscreen devices. the individual browser could sometimes reinterpret it to work like an `onclick`, but that's a crapshoot.

instead use `onmouseover` and `onclick` for desktop, so you have the failover to `onclick` for touchscreen.